# Can i put logo inside the figure?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, figure

Can i put logo nested with anchor inside the `<figure>` ? Is it right?
Here is the code

```
<header>
    <div class="row">
      <figure class="col-sm-5"> <a href="index.html" class="logo"> <img src="images/logo.gif" class="img-responsive" height="60" width="330" alt="site-logo"> </a> </figure>
      <div class="col-sm-7">
        <div class="well">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-9"><nav></nav></div>
            <figure class="col-xs-3"> <img src="images/helpline.gif" class="img-responsive" height="60" width="120" alt="helpline-image"> </figure>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
  </header>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Or at least explain what's not working. Maybe put your code in a Fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For better SEO, put your logo inside H2 tag.

```
<h2>
   <a href="#">
      <img src="logo.gif" alt="stackoverflow-logo"/> 
   </a>
</h2>
```

Give proper name for alternate text tag `alt`, instead of site logo, give your companyname-logo

Comment: Can't i put logo inside the <figure> ? Is there any problem? As i know, we need to nest images by <figure>. Isn't it?

Comment: You can put inside figure tag also, but when SEO crawlers first scan your H1 tag , so you have to put meaning full info about your site.Next your H2, so if you need better SEO, place your logo inside H2.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can.

> The HTML `<figure>` element represents self-contained content, frequently with a caption (`<figcaption>`), and is typically referenced as a single unit. While it is related to the main flow, its position is independent of the main flow. Usually this is an image, an illustration, a diagram, a code snippet, or a schema that is referenced in the main text, but that can be moved to another page or to an appendix without affecting the main flow.

Reference : [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figure)

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old, but please do not place your logo in an `<h2>`; it is not the place for it and can mess up your accessibility, your dom heading structure, and your SEO performance. Doing something because you can, does not make it the right solution below are some links about how to use heading tags. If you want it to look like an `<h2>`, then style it in your CSS.

[W3 Schools](https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/page-structure/headings/)

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Heading_Elements#Accessibility_concerns)

[SEO and Headers Article](https://www.hobo-web.co.uk/headers/)

Comment: Thank you so much. I think just putting logo inside "a" tag and wrapping by div or nav would be better.